# Why does let generate error but var doesnt

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

In Google App Script both old and new editor this causes an error

```
function sortSheets() {
  try {
    let ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  }
  catch(err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
}
```

> Syntax error: Missing ; before statement. line: 16 file: Code

But this does not.

```
function sortSheets() {
  try {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  }
  catch(err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you using a stand alone project or bounded project?  Does the project has other content? What is above the code included here in the project giving you problems? What runtime is you project using?

Comment: Are you sure you are using the latest version of Google Scripts? https://www.labnol.org/es6-google-apps-script-v8-200206

Comment: I completely forgot about the V8 runtime.  Thats it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I completely forgot about the V8 runtime.  When off I get that message, obviously because the old runtime did not have `let`.

[image]